# Using filestream to implement high scores

Tags: c++, filestream

I'm writing a game in C++ using OpenGL and I'm having trouble using filestreams to import scores to the file and export them to the program to be displayed.

I have the following functions to import and export high scores: (some code in there was me trying to debug the problem)

```
void DisplayScores(void) // is going to be called by LoadHighScores()

{

glRasterPos2i(HighScore::x, HighScore::y);
printString(lineholder);

HighScore::y -= 15;
std::cout << "lineholder before being cleared: " << lineholder << std::endl;
lineholder = "";

}

void LoadScores(void) // Loads the high scores // called when the high scores option     on the main menu has been selected

{

std::ifstream scorelist("scorelist.txt");

while (!scorelist.eof())

{

    scorelist.get(getletter);

    switch(getletter)

    {

        case '\n': DisplayScores(); break;
        default: lineholder = lineholder + getletter; break;

    }

}

scorelist.close();

}

void AddScore(char* name, int score) // takes arguments of the name of the player who has     just played the game and their score is also passed and copied to the config file

{

std::ofstream addscore("scorelist.txt", std::ios::app);

addscore << name; // name of the player achieving the score
addscore << ":"; // if addscore.get() == ':' you know the score is going to come after this
addscore << score;
addscore << std::endl; // end the line in the text file so when you encounter '\n' you     know you need to translate to a new line to display someone elses score

addscore.close();

}
```

and the following piece of code that uses the functions: (the else statement is part of a main menu branch that is called if "Play" has not been selected)

```
else

{

    // display the high scores here
    std::cout << "in the else statement";
    LoadScores();
    AddScore("this", 20);

}
```

When I build the program I simply get "In the else statement" but nothing is written to the score file and DisplayScores() is seemingly not called either.

the text file simply contains the following:

```
Nick 10 
Jason 50
```

Comment: Why the sdl tag? You are not really using SDL at any important places for this questions. The usage of SDL in other parts of the programm unrelated to this question should not make you tag your question this way.

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

`while( !scorelist.eof() )` is almost never what you want. `istream::eof()` is set after the first read went wrong, so checking `istream::eof()` at the beginning of the loop means, that the loop is entered, all data is read, then processed. Then when the `eof` is reached, instead of reading data the flag is set (in the reading function). Then all processing is done (because the loop is not aborted) and then finally the flag is seen. This often results in the last line of the file being written twice.

Other than that, your code to call `LoadScores()` is commented out. If this is the actuall code you are using, then this is your problem. If it is not the actuall code you are using, please update your question and I will have another look.

Comment: My mistake on commenting out LoadScores() in the question, I am aware using while is not the way to go about this but it should at least do something (even if that is writing the last line twice at least I know it is working) and even then, the AddScore() function does not work either.

Comment: Just to add, I entered a further comment at the end of the LoadScores() function to the console, this comment isn't displayed so it's also as if the end of LoadScores() is never being reached which I can't see how that is possible. Another thing; I've only just noticed upon ending the process the integer 3 is returned, however the end of my program should return 0.

Comment: @Michael: still, even with your code changes I cannot compile and test your program. When asking for help, you should try to produce minimal compileable code for checking. Then tell what you expect to happen and what actually is happening. This way others can check and debug your actual code. Also producing such a minimal example will often help finding the problem. If you remove a seemingly unrelated line and the error goes away, that line was the cause.

Comment: The program I would be including in the question would be over 1000 lines of code long. From the experience (albeit somewhat small) I have of C++, I can see absolutely no reason why the functions in the else statement wouldn't be called at all, however, I have previously had problems with SDL similar to this one and the problem could be to do with SDL (as it replaces main() with its own version of main()) and also cout << is redirected to a stdout.txt file in the executable location as no console is present upon execution

Comment: @Michael: no, do not poste the full programm. 1000 lines of code is definitely too much. That is why I said you should post **minimal** compilable examples. Start by reducing your program part by part. If you remove something either the error will stay, in which case you can remove that part from the minimal example, or it will go away, in which case you are directed to the actual location of the error.

Comment: @Michael: Having said that: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted, except for the things I have pointed out above. So no one will be able to help you except for taking a shot and guessing. If you want people to help you, you need to provide them with the information they need. I could try to make more guesses what could be wrong, but I really do not like to. It's your turn now to provide everybody with more info to verify their guesses. Do not expect people to help you, unless you are willing to do your part of the work. (see http://homepage1.nifty.com/algafield/sscce.html)